# Problem when trying to fill out a django form with MultiSelectField field

Tags: python-3.x, django

When filling in the field and clicking send, the message "Make sure the value has a maximum of 5 characters (it has 10) appears." I've already tried several manipulations in models.py but nothing worked. I need this field to accept more than one value selected by the user to be saved in the database.I don't think I know where to move.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from courses.models import CourseCategory
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    areas_of_interest_choices = (
        ('TI', 'Tecnologia da Informação'),
        ('ADM', 'Administração'),
        ('CTB', 'Contabilidade'),
        ('EC', 'Economia'),
        ('FI', 'Finanças'),
        ('SA', 'Saúde'),
        ('LI', 'Linguagens'),
        ('GA', 'Gastronomia'),
    )


    escolaridade_choices = (
        ('FC', 'Fundamental Completo'),
        ('FI', 'Fundamental Incompleto'),
        ('MC', 'Médio Completo'),
        ('MI', 'Médio Incompleto'),
        ('SC', 'Superior Completo'),
        ('SI', 'Superior Incompleto')
    )

    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, verbose_name='CPF', blank=False, null=False) 
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Data de Nascimento')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Telefone')
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='CEP')
    education = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=escolaridade_choices, verbose_name='Escolaridade')
    areas_of_interest = MultiSelectField(blank=True, null=True, max_choices=3,
                                         max_length=5,choices=areas_of_interest_choices)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser, CourseCategory
from django import forms



class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "full_name", "cpf", "date_of_birth", "email", 
                  "telephone", "zip_code", "education", "areas_of_interest")

    queryset = CourseCategory.objects.all()
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': forms.SelectDateWidget(),
        'areas_of_interest': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['areas_of_interest'].queryset = CourseCategory.objects.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data["date_of_birth"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
    

    def clean_areas_of_interest(self):
        areas_of_interest = self.cleaned_data.get("areas_of_interest")
        if not self.instance.is_superuser and not areas_of_interest:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Este campo é obrigatório.")
        return areas_of_interest
    
    

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("username", "full_name", "cpf", "date_of_birth", "email", 
                  "telephone", "zip_code", "education", "areas_of_interest")
        
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': forms.SelectDateWidget(),
        'areas_of_interest': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['areas_of_interest'].queryset = CourseCategory.objects.all()
```

There are the files I'm currently trying to get working. I'm wanting to make all the data be saved in the database correctly.

Comment: `areas_of_interest` is not a database field in your code. The classes in the models must derive from `models` baseClass (like you did in `education = models.CharField(...)` for example).